# Code (C++) to html converter for Forums

Tags: c++, html

I have searched for quite some time and was unable to find a program that is able to convert code to html quickly for use in forums, but not web-pages, in which case it cannot use style-sheets and does not output (or has the option to turn off) all extraneous tags such as html, body etc. Does it exist? If not, then I know what my next side project will be...

Comment: That depends on what HTML or markup the particular forum(s) you're interested in allow.  Most forums only allow a very small whitelisted set of tags in posts.

Comment: I am assuming that the forum allows the font tag and coloring. The pre tag can be optional (the html code will look ugly, but who cares, it is going to be hidden :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found one that does exactly what I want it to do. The reason it was not showing up easily in search results is due to its name, Source to Html (instead of Code to Html).

http://www.newty.de/lsc/

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Passing `noclasses=True` to [Pygment's](http://pygments.org/) [`HTMLFormatter`](http://pygments.org/docs/formatters/#htmlformatter) will tell it to use inline styles instead of CSS. This should also be supported in its `pygmentize` command.

Answer (score 0):

In SO, we are able to give syntax highlighting to our codes. This is something similar to what you would want. Though, I am not sure if there is one you can readily use which is implemented in C++.